# Saving output of for loop in separate data frames

Tags: r, for-loop

I've got a simple problem that I haven't been able to solve despite the many similar posts, because I'm a bit of a knucklehead in R, and I'm not getting whatever it is I should be getting.  I have two sets of files,

```
All.Files <- objects(pattern="constant.country[0-9]{4}")
all.files <- objects(pattern="constant[0-9]{4}")
```

that I wish to merge

```
mergefun <- function(X1, Y1) {
    merge(X1, Y1, by = "id")
}
```

and then save each iteration of merge into a new dataframe

```
for (i in All.Files) {
    a <- get(i)
      { for (j in all.files)
         b <- get(j)
         d <- dataframe(mergefun(a, b))
         newname <- paste("C", substr(j, 9, 12), sep="")
         names(d) <- c("Id", "Country", "logGDP", "GRI", GRI.group", "Year")
         assign(newname,d)

       }  
    }
```

While I am sure there is more elegant code out there, this code does what I want it to.  The problem is that it is only saving the final iteration of merge, so that instead of getting 1:43 dataframes, I only get the 43rd.  I know I am failing to index properly within the for loop, but I have struggled for hours to understand my mistake and have failed.

I am sorry I have not included a reproducible example, but was hopeful that because my code actually worked, someone would be able to instantly see what I am missing that would allow all 43 iterations to get outputted via assign.  I am also aware that mapply would likely be a better solution, but I was unable to get any traction with it despite several hours of trying!

A most humble (and humbled by my own ignoRance) thank you.

Comment: Is that the EXACT code you're using?  If so, you have an extra quote after `GRI.group`.

Comment: funny--that's the only line of code I changed. I took out a few column headers to simplify it and messed up the quote when doing so.  So no, there are no issues with improper quotes when I run it.  I get no errors at all; my problem is that I only get iteration 43 outputted as a df.

Comment: Do you have an issue where the substring of j you are pulling out is always the same?

Comment: Just took another look at your code.  Your brackets are messed up.

Comment: In what sense are they messed up?

Comment: sorry--still figuring out what is showing up where.  learning!

Comment: No problem.  Do you understand how that bracketing issue was affecting your code?

Comment: @ 3rd comment--no, the naming convention worked properly on all the merges once you fixed the brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (i in All.Files) {
a <- get(i)
   for (j in all.files) {
     b <- get(j)
     d <- dataframe(mergefun(a, b))
     newname <- paste("C", substr(j, 9, 12), sep="")
     names(d) <- c("Id", "Country", "logGDP", "GRI", "GRI.group", "Year")
     assign(newname,d)

   }  
}
```

I fixed your bracketing.  It should also be clear that since your `newname` only relies on `j` that it will be the case that your new variables will only be created on the LAST iteration of the outer `for` loop.  Thus, you end up with only `length(all.files)` variables.

Comment: Thank you!  What you did works.  It took me a few minutes to sort out why having the bracket enclose the j for-loop caused the problem, but I see it now.  Thank you for answering such a simple question--taught me s/thing I'll use in all my new code construction.

Comment: No problem.  Happy to help, especially since you formed your question well.  Do heed the fact that the vars you are creating only rely on `j`!  I think your code won't output quite what you want as is!

Comment: Rats.  You are right.  Back to the drawing board.  In original code it only gave me iteration 43 but it was the correct output.  Now I get all 43 outputs and they are wrong. One step at a time, eh?

Comment: Just have you `newname` variable rely on an identifier from `i`.  This will make them unique.

Comment: Even if I use i in the newname it still only uses the last iteration of j in each merge (but it uses i[1:43].

Comment: newname <- paste("C", substr(i, 17, 20), sep="")

Comment: only other change to code since original posting is fixing the brackets.

Comment: It needs to rely on `i` AND `j`!!!! Think about how many variables you would end up with!!!!